# How to reverse a list in VB?

Tags: vb.net, string, list, reverse, s-expression

I am working with LISP expressions in my computer programming (visual basic) course and I have a minor question.

**How would I go about reversing a list in vb.net?**

For example, if I were to input:

```
'(H J K L)
```

I would return an output of:

```
'(L K J H)
```

Answer (score 5):

if for instance you have a list of strings, you can simple call the Reverse() method which is available for IEnumerable

```
Dim list = New List(Of String)() From { _
    "item", _
    "item2", _
    "item3" _
}

list.Reverse()
```

Or if you were dealing with an array of strings it would be as below.

```
Dim arr = New String() {"kdkd", "dkd"}

Dim reversedArr = arr.Reverse()
```

Comment: And if you have a string that looks like "(H J K L)", you should be able to use the Trim and Split methods of the String Class to convert it into an array of String {"H", "J", "K", "L"}.